# Visual Studio, can't find reference Microsoft Excel Object Library

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

[image]As you can see it's not in my reference library anyone know how to get it there?

Comment: Why not use `Interop` if looking at automating `Excel`? On another note, if `Office` is not installed on your development system, the related type libraries will not be available either. Finally, there isn't a separate library because they are actually embedded in the `exe` itself.

Comment: The interop methods have changed from time to time, and that library probably isn't supported in your version of visual studio. You may just need a different one (or a different approach for office interop)

Comment: Do you have Office installed on this machine?

Comment: Yes I do have office installed, yet it is the 2019 version maybe that is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my search, you must install office application. If you want to know more about

it,  you could look at the following link.

[How to download the microsoft excel 16.0 object library](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3dd233f9-8d26-44af-854b-cdbb86897637/how-to-download-the-microsoft-excel-160-object-library?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Then, you can find the library in the following picture.
[image]

Comment: Yes that's true but I already have office installed, except both visual studio and office are 2019 verion so maybe that is the problem?

Comment: what is your current office and visual studio? I only tested with vs2019 and office 2016. so I am not sure what happened if you installed other versions of vs2019 and office.